# How do I get a direct download from a path like /media/<media id>?

Tags: 8, media

i'm wondering how anyone using drupal 8 is handling files using the newly added to core media module. For example, uploading a document using media module, to be linked to by multiple pieces of content, and not having to upload the same file on every page. I just want to be able to link to /media/{media id} and have the doc download or open in the browser.

Any idea on how to get this done?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/media_entity_download